# How to change Total Item name in ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have used ng-grid.I wish to change name of 'Total Item ' to something another name.I have tried footerTemplate in `gridOption` like.But How to get also total number of items in footerTemplate

I following this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/31flwE?p=preview

Comment: Not sure where you are trying to put the totals. You can simply add them where you are writing the totals as a text.         `footerTemplate: '<div style="width: 200px; display: inline-block;">Totals: {{total1}}</div><div style="width: 200px; display: inline-block;">{{total2}}</div><div style="width: 200px; display: inline-block;">{{total3}}</div>'`

Comment: It just for demo.i want total number of data(rows) in total.

Comment: You can just use the data and get the record count from the array to get your record counts.  Remember, that the ng-Grid will only show a subset of records (if you have 1000s) for speed, so counting on screen is not accurate, but your controller could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ng-grid.min.js file..

ngTotalItemsLabel: "Total Items:",

find  "ngTotalItemsLabel: "Total Items:","  in your ng-grid.min.js file and just change "Total Items" to your selected text..
Thank You